# Why are my torrents not downloading?

Tags: transmission

I am using transmission-daemon and controlling it through the webgui.

Currently I have two torrents from separate trackers that are on 0B of OB status. I am using transmission. On one torrent at last announce it says "got 50 peers" the other "got 48 peers."

port 51413 is listed as open

I have changed the ownership of the download folder to debian-transmission

Any ideas? I'm fresh out of troubleshooting steps.

Comment: How many seeds does it say you have?

Comment: @Seth 142 and 47 seeders

Answer (score 28):

In my case, it was also helpful to change the setting of the random port picking option to **true**. In transmission, you do it by following these instructions:

**Edit** → **Preferences** → **Network Tab** → Tick the first box

Comment: if the port is closed when you test it as above, just have transmission select a random port and exit from transmission.  When you next run transmission it will probably just work.

Answer (score 6):

I had the problem.
The cause was the client being unauthorized.

To solve the issue, I changed the settings:

1. Stop daemon: `sudo service transmission-daemon stop`
2. Edit the settings: `sudo vim /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` (replace vim with your favourite text editor)
3. Unrequire authentication: "rpc-authentication-required": false
4. Whitelist localhost: "rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1"
5. Restart daemon: `sudo service transmission-daemon start`

And now it works. If you suffered from this issue, it's possible that download-dir changed as well. so I suggest you check that option too and change it to your desire:

"download-dir": "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/Downloads"

Comment: Most useful for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I switched to port 57558 and it now functions. I'm not sure if this is a long-term solution, but in any case shows that this is network issue and not something related to transmission.
Thanks everyone for their help.

Comment: Perhaps my isp is blocking 51413? I understand that this is common port for torrenting?

Comment: That is a very good possibility. Or perhaps you're in a NATed network where something else is using the external port, making you unreachable to the outside world? Many possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. Changed the *peer-port-random-on-start* to *true* as suggested. Still was unable to download. Checked on some of the other forums & found a tool called "*deluge*". Installed it on my Ubuntu 16.10 machine & the downloads are working fine now. Wonder what was the issue with transmission.

Below is the link to install deluge on Ubuntu 16.10 :

https://www.linuxbabe.com/bittorrent/deluge-bittorrent-client-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Deluge is in the standard repositories with only a point release difference...

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the setting `peer-port-random-on-start` from `false` to `true`. That did the trick for me(transmission-daemon).

Comment: how did you do that can you explain ?

Comment: $ sudo vim /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json

Comment: Oddly, this worked. And I had opened up the port with iptables and tested with nmap

Answer (score 0):

I have AT&T at home and I was messing around with my router. I have always had the NetBIOS protocol turn off, but I had disabled the **All Other Protocols** option on my system.  It appears that Transmission used one of the vague protocols with my router. As soon as I re-enabled it, I was able to get Transmission to work for me.

HTTP
HTTPS
FTP 
Telnet
SMTP
DNS
*NetBIOS*
POP3
IMAP
NNTP
IRC 
H323
**All Other Protocols**

Answer (score 0):

Adding port forwarding rules for the values in `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` called `peer-port-random-high` and `peer-port-random-low` on your router (for me it was `65535` and `49152`) and then again on your device with `ufw allow low:high/tcp` worked for me.